# Plotar na horizontal (coluna a coluna) - Python

Tags: python, xml, csv

Boa tarde, amigos

Tudo bem?

Estou com um arquivo em XML do qual gostaria de retirar os dados conforme apresentado abaixo e plotar em colunas, não linha a linha como o código está realizando, no caso os dados ficariam lado a lado (horizontal).

```
tree =  ET.parse('/content/drive/My Drive/Python/Download CVM/Extract/DFP/00759520191231401/InfoFinaDFin.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
xml_data_to_csv = open('Out.csv', 'w')
list_head=[]
Csv_writer=csv.writer(xml_data_to_csv)
count=0

for element in root.findall('InfoFinaDFin'):
  List_nodes =[]
  #Get head by tag
  if count == 0:
    #get child node
    
    DescricaoConta1 = element.find('DescricaoConta1').text
    List_nodes.append(DescricaoConta1)
    
  
    #Write List_nodes to csv
    Csv_writer.writerow(List_nodes)
  
#close csv file

xml_data_to_csv.close()
```

**Resultado do código apresentado: (Gostaria que ficasse: 1 row x 859 columns)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia colocar um trecho do XML para facilitar a compreensão.

Da forma que está, você pode tentar simplesmente guardar os valores numa lista e depois escrever num arquivo separados por virgula. Assim ao ler como csv ele estaria como o esperado, com uma linha e 858 colunas:

```
tree =  ET.parse('/content/drive/My Drive/Python/Download CVM/Extract/DFP/00759520191231401/InfoFinaDFin.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
colunas = []

for element in root.findall('InfoFinaDFin'):
    DescricaoConta1 = element.find('DescricaoConta1').text
    colunas.append(DescricaoConta1)
  

with open('Out.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write(','.join(colunas))
```